# Removing Tests in Rails 3.1

Tags: testing, rspec, ruby-on-rails-3.1

Quick simple question: I do not want any test cases, fixtures, etc in my Rails 3.1.rc5 app. Is it safe to remove everything in the `test` folder? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's 'safe' in the sense that it will not break your app.